# Scala parallel collections, threads termination, and sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using parallel collections, and when my application terminates, sbt issues:

`Not interrupting system thread Thread[process reaper,10,system]`

It issues this message one time per core (minus one to be precise).

I have seen in sbt code that this is by design, but I am not sure why don't the threads terminate along with my application. Any insight would be appreciated if you were unlucky enough to come across the same...

Comment: AFAIK, JVM will wait for any non-daemon thread to complete even if your main method has finished. Can you share some sample code to replicate the behaviour you described?

Comment: Yeah well I know, question is rather why would any threads out-survive my main method, in general. I'll try to extract generic sample code indeed... till then just wondered what can be a generic explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel collections by default are backed by `ForkJoinTasks.defaultForkJoinPool`, which is a `lazy val`, so it's created the first time it's used.

Like any [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), it runs until explicitly shut down. The pool has no way of knowing whether it's going to receive any new tasks, and thread creation is relatively expensive, so it would be wasteful for the pool to shut down when it was empty only to start up again as soon as new tasks are added. So its threads hang around unless and until the pool is explicitly shut down.

As a design decision the JVM doesn't kill other threads just because the main thread terminates; in some programming styles the main thread terminates relatively early (e.g. think about web servers where the main thread sets up everything, starts a pool of dispatcher threads, and then exits, but the web server continues to run indefinitely).

You could call `ForkJoinTasks.defaultForkJoinPool.shutdown()` once you know you're not going to do any more parallel operations, or you could create parallel collections using a custom pool that's explicitly controlled from your code.

Comment: It seems sbt is just being polite notifying that it keeps these threads up